# How to get all posts from the User's subscriptions

Tags: php, laravel

In my application, I have setup a User model that can have subscribers and subscriptions through a pivot table called `subscriptions`.

```
public function subscribers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Forum\User', 'subscriptions', 'subscription_id', 'subscriber_id');
}

public function subscriptions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Forum\User', 'subscriptions', 'subscriber_id', 'subscription_id');
}
```

My question is, what relationship should I use to get a list of paginated Post models (belong to a User) from the User's subscriptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `whereHas` method to filter based on relationships. Assuming your `Post` model has a `user` relationship defined, your code would look something like:

```
// target user
$user = \App\User::first();
$userId = $user->id;

// get all of the posts that belong to users that have your target user as a subscriber
\App\Post::whereHas('user.subscribers', function ($query) use ($userId) {
    return $query->where('id', $userId);
})->paginate(10);
```

You can read more about [querying relationship existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
\App\Post::with(['subscriptions' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('date', 'like', '%date%');
}])->paginate(15);
```

Or without any conditions

```
\App\Post::with('subscriptions')->paginate(15);
```

Comment: How would that work since the subscriptions and subscribers relation methods are part of the User model?

Comment: You want to pull all post to which a user has subscribed. Right ?

Comment: I want to paginate the list of posts from all accounts to which the user is subscribed to.

Comment: Then these methods should be added to the Post model